# Android widget - bind service again when application forced stop

Tags: android, service, widget, bind

This is my short description about my widget and main application. Sorry because of my English (English is not my mother tongue)

I have a music player widget. When this widget enabled, I need bind to a music player service (A) of main application. Because we cannot bind a service in AppWidgetProvider so I start a local service (B) in AppWidgetProvider and bind to that music player service (A) from here. Furthermore, I also have a service C to do widget's button function.

Everything seems to be working fine but when my main app with service A all forced stop (they will be restating a moment later) I must rebind to A from widget. Problem is when main app was forced stop, I cannot rebind to A because context(I stored Context as a global variable in AppWidgetProvider whenever I receive context from onEnabled, onUpdate) is NULL.

My question is how about my above widget structure? Should service B stoped when bind to A done? How can i bind to service A again when main app and service a was forced stop (but they will automatically restart a moment later).

Thanks you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer my own question

1. First, We can bind Service from widget, using `context.getApplicationContext().bindService(..)`
2. When main application was forced stop, to bind service again on onUpdate() use application context `MyMainApplication.Instance().getApplicationContext().bindService(..)`